# Master Detail ID For Foreign key in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entity, master-detail

I have three Tables,
one of them is (Scenario) which is the Master table,
two other tables (Link, Node) are it's details.
I want JPA persist the foreign key for me while persisting Scenario in link and Node Tables  without my intervention,
is there any one help me do this???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLajm.jpg)

Scenario:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Scenario.findAll", query = "select o from Scenario o") })
public class Scenario implements Serializable {
private String className;
@Id
@Column(nullable = false,name="ID")
private int id;
private String linkFromPortIdProperty;
private String linkToPortIdProperty;
private String UUID;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<Link> linkDataArray;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario1", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<Node> nodeDataArray;
```

Link:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Lnk.findAll", query = "select o from Link o") })
@Table(name = "LNK", schema = "DEV_SGMNT")

public class Link implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5262332521707870082L;


@Transient
private String to;
private int fromPort;
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;
private double[] points;
@Transient
private String from;
private int toPort;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SCENARIO_ID")
private Scenario scenario;
```

Node:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Node.findAll", query = "select o from Node o") })
public class Node implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8401815303355236645L;
private String classname;
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;
private BigDecimal inbound;
private String key;
private BigDecimal outbound;
private String properties;
private String tab;
private String text;
private String vizitems;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SCENARIO_ID")
private Scenario scenario1;
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by `no intervention`. But, for the sake of clarity, I suggest you add in your code snippet the code you use to save `...persist(link)` and the expected result in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CascadeType.ALL for all detail objects you want to persist when the master entity (Scenario) is persisted.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
private List<Link> linkDataArray;
```

Read this guide written by vladmihalcea:

[Reference](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)